# How to manipulate the address of a current object in c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, object, reference

Well hi, i'm doing a C++ project and for days i try to make a two classe's with no inheritance relevance where i need to make functions which manipulate each other's objects.Well i thought if i wanted the address of a current object from one class,Room and wanna make a function to the other class Reservation i need to find a way to somehow pass the address of the current object Room at the function(or at least a reference).Let me give an example:

```
       void  Reservation::antToDomKratisis(Room &domatio){


         domatioOfKratisiPtr=&domatio;

 }
```

In the above code domatioOfKratisiPtr has been declares as int* domatioKratisiPtr=0; in the Reservation constructor and i try to make it  point to a Room object or at least a reference here.Is there a better way to do this?Also in the other class Room i do this:

```
 bool Room::addReservation(Reservation &reserv){
  bool successOfReservation;

   for(int i=0; i<30; i++){

if(tableRoomAvailability[i]==0 && Reservation::getAtoma()<=getMaxAtoma()){//

    for(int j=i;j<i+Reservation::getMeresDiamonis();j++){ 

        tableRoomAvailability[j]=&reserv;

    }
     successOfReservation=true;//mporese na ginei i kratisi sto domatio

}
else
    successOfReservation=false;

    }
    Reservation::antToDomKratisis(Room &domatio);

    return successOfReservation;


}
```

Let me explain the code.Here i have a tableRoomAvailability table which has 30 pointers to Reservation objects,getAtoma() is a method of Reservation which returns the max people for a Reservation ,getMeresDiamonis return the days people in the room which they reserved they ll stay and if the pointer in the table does not point to a Reservtion object(meaning this day for instance its free for reservation) and also the individual for the reservation is less than the max (getMaxAtoma) then i make each cell of the table many as the MeresDiamonis(days of staying) to be pointing to the spesific Reservation object.At the end **i call antToDomKratisis() in order to have domatioOfKratisiPtr point to the current Room object of the reservation** but how to even pass the address of a reference or the object itself because i create one in main?I thought of this but i dont think it would work the way i portrayed.

Comment: Try to simplify the question, what you want to achieve? and what are the errors you are facing

Comment: can i simply ask without giving code if there is a way to get and manipulate the address of a current object and make a function in another type of class able to recognise that object?

Comment: Create a minimal compilable example and boil down the question. You will get better answers and avoid downvotes.

Comment: Well i was sure i was not much of clear here ,but i basically wanted to ask the above statement in the comment i made but i feared without code it wouldnt make a point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside an object you refer itself using the keyword ***this***.
So, if i understood your question, you can do something like:

```
void  Reservation::antToDomKratisis(Room *domatio){
     domatioOfKratisiPtr=domatio;
}
```

And then call it, inside your Room object:

```
reserv.antToDomKratisis(this);
```

I also advice you to save the pointer in the right type, so the member domatioOfKratisiPtr of Reservation object should be:

```
Room *domatioOfKratisiPtr;
```

Comment: one question only further i did all this exactly and i initialize domatioOfKratisiPtr as 0 and then even i use it calling the function antToDomKratisis() in Room class but it says unusable variable domatioOfKratisiPtr pointing to my declaration of it in the Reservation constructor.